# I need to Play .M4V foramt audio from url, Problem with playing .M4V format

Tags: android

i have a url for the video file. the format of that file is itunes M4V.

I applied the URL in Api demos example, which is playing for some time, after sometime song is breaking.

Is there any problem with this format or any way to play .M4V format.

Please let me know...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not support .m4v containers ([Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html))